# What is the default method in raster package R resample?

Tags: raster, r, resampling

What is the default method in the resample command from the raster package in R? 
I see that you can chose some methods like bilinear or nearest neighbor, but what is the default? This is important for me so I can stick to one method also when I resample with another software. Is the default method 'bilinear' because it is used in the example in the package documentation?

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/resample

Comment: If you want to ensure consistency in code then always use the "method" argument when calling the raster::resample function and explicitly define the resampling method used. Just be aware that nominal data should always use nearest neighbor and bilinear is a good choice for continuous (floating point) data. Cubic convolution resampling can provide smoother results but can also estimate outside the range of observed data.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Is there a way to resample using Cubic Convolution method using `raster` or another R package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `bilinear` is the default method used in the `resample()` function. You can see that in the usage section of the help file:

```
Usage

# S4 method for Raster,Raster
resample(x, y, method="bilinear", filename="", ...)
```